# Error while connecting to sqlite. Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlcipher, pysqlite, pysqlcipher

I am trying to make a connection to my (pysqlcipher) encrypted sqlite database but I am failing because PRAGMA key input is incorrect. I have my correct password 'test' in a separate .env file.

Even though everything should be correct I get the following ERROR message: *Error while connecting to sqlite. Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.*

How can I solve this? I think it is syntax error.

**.env file**

```
DATABASE_SECRET_KEY = test
```

**PYTHON SCRIPT**

```
import sqlite3
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request, flash, redirect, url_for, session
from pysqlcipher3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3

sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('./database/test.db')
cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()

PRAGMA_key = os.environ.get("DATABASE_SECRET_KEY")
cursor.execute("PRAGMA key = \'%s\';", [PRAGMA_key])

print("Successfully Connected to SQLite")
```

**ERROR**

```
Error while connecting to sqlite.

Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Maybe try string formatting `f"PRAGMA key = '{PRAGMA_key}';"`. As I know `execute` may not replace some values in query - for example it can't put table name to query `SELECT * FROM %s`. All for security reason.

Comment: Furas, your solutions worked! Thank you!